# Laravel eager loading using data inside itself

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I'm trying to use data inside some eager loading in Laravel.

I have a "Sensors" table with many "Measurements" in another one.

I need to check every measurement a sensor has every hour. When I do it, it saves the last id of the measurement checked inside "sensors.last_checked_measurement"

```
$sensors = Sensor::with(array('measurements' => function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '>', SENSOR.LAST_CHECKED_MEASUREMENT); // <-- in between data
}))->get();
```

This, as you may know, translate into

```
"select * from 'sensors'"
"select * from `measurements` where `measurements`.`sensor_id` in (?, ?) and `id` > ?"
```

If Laravel can use the result of the first query to get the sensor_id for the next one, maybe it can be done, right?

So my question:

**How can I use that "SENSOR.LAST_CHECKED_MEASUREMENT" inside the eager loading?**

Comment: Doesn't the first block of code do what you want? Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: SENSOR.LAST_CHECKED_MEASUREMENT it's supposed to be inside the table for 'sensors', and until i got the get() after with() it can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried db::raw?

```
$sensors = Sensor::with(array('measurements' => function($query) {
    $query->where('id', '>', DB::raw('SELECT LAST_CHECKED_MEASUREMENT FROM SENSOR ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1'));
}))->get();
```

Comment: This looks like what they are asking for.

Comment: Maybe it does, but is not exactly what I'm asking.

Comment: The idea is use data from the first query onto the second one.
Look at the SQL translation.